# How to click on elements which "Displayed = False"

Tags: selenium-webdriver, c#

I was trying to click on a element by finding it using `classname`
But i got an error saying element is not visible.

Then i debug the code and saw `"Displayed = False"` .

[image]
But the element is fully visible to be.
So the Question is why this happens and how to overcome this king of situation.

Comment: make it displayed using JavascriptExecutor. But its really weird that you can see it but selenium cant click it.

Comment: @ChathuD: Have you sort it out? I'm facing the same issue with Chrome Web Driver.

Comment: @el.severo i skip this test case. :( , I could not find a better solution .

Answer (score 1):

If element is not displayed, user would not be able to interact with it, so your test (which should emulate what user would do) shod not be able to do anything with it either.

IOW it is not a bug, it is a feature.

Comment: Thats the problem ,even its property set to display =falls ,its available on the webpage,use can click on ot.

Comment: If what you say is true (which I doubt), you found a bug in the browser rendering engine. Most likely there is some other element, which is enabled, and you are looking in a wrong place.

Answer (score 0):

Try using javascript click event. I am tagging the stackoverflow answer here. Let me know if this works for you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11947832/how-to-click-an-element-in-selenium-webdriver-using-javascript